# Creating eclipse project from main method

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Is there anyway to create temporary eclipse project and workspace from simple Java main method? I have the following code for now:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        IProgressMonitor progress = new NullProgressMonitor();
        IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
        IWorkspaceRoot root = workspace.getRoot();

        IProject project = root.getProject();

        IProjectDescription desc = workspace.newProjectDescription(project.getName());
        IPath path = new Path("./project/");
        desc.setLocation(path);

        project.create(desc, progress);
        project.open(progress);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But this fails to exception "Workspace is closed". I know there must be some kind of initialization of the workspace using org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main but how is this done programatically? Tried to find solutions but after an hour of googling I couldn't find any.

Thanks!

Comment: Only plugins can do these operations. This is not possible in plain Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no, depending on the perspective.

Calling just API will not work, as the newly launched VM did not execute all the startup functions of necessary plugins, even if you have added them to the classpath, hence f.e. all the paths were missing.

You have two options to try to solve that:

1. Create [a full-blown RCP application](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#exercise-creating-an-eclipse-rcp-application).
2. Try to run your app in the same VM as Eclipse (I'm not sure if there is such a toggle in the Run... configuration).
3. Probably most recommended - create your [own plugin with an action](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-action-contribution/index.html) that will do what you want and install it in your Eclipse.